# In-place operations and user defined functions

Tags: python, copy, deep-copy

What is the conventional wisdom around using in-place operations within user defined functions?  Using in-place operations in side of user defined functions will violate the "no-side-effect" maxim which user defined functions usually abide.  This is very dangerous! For example:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)

X = np.random.rand(4,2)

def my_shuffle(Y):
    np.random.shuffle(Y)
    return(Y)

print(X)
print(my_shuffle(X))
print(X) #Oops
```

My solution:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)

X = np.random.rand(4,2)

def my_shuffle_fix(Y):
    import copy
    Y_copy = copy.deepcopy(Y)
    np.random.shuffle(Y_copy)
    return(Y_copy)

print(X)
print(my_shuffle_fix(X))
print(X) #Better
```

Is this a good work around?

Comment: It's completely normal for user-defined functions to have side effects. It's unusual for a Python function to mutate *and* return its input, though.

Comment: Keep in mind that making copies is wasteful, so don't do it if you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks!  I guess what you're both saying is that if you don't want your function to have side-effects then don't use in-place operators. Makes sense! I guess I should use a different approach to shuffle the array.

Comment: many times we create new list/dictionary from old one using list/dictionary comprehension - so we don't have to use `copy`

Comment: @JacobH -- You can write a function to shuffle the array -- Just don't _return_ anything.  That makes it clear that the function mutated the arguments or had some other side-effect (e.g. just like `np.random.shuffle`)